# Confused About Money-Rails Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, money-rails

I'm working my way through basic calculator app ...

Trying to integrate money-gem in it but confused ...

This is the current schema (as you can see, it doesn't have any columns ending with `_cents` ... and very confused if the `_cents` part is needed ...

**Current Schema**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170301051956) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "tippies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.float    "tip",        null: false
    t.decimal  "cost",       null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

In the model, I added `monetize :tip` & `monetize: cost` ...

Do I need to modify the `tip` and `cost` columns in the schema, ie, remake it to be integer, and add the post `_cents` part?

**Current Model**

```
class Tippy < ApplicationRecord

    validates :tip, presence: true
    validates :cost, presence: true

    monetize :tip
    monetize :cost


    TIP_CHOICES = { "10%" => ".10", "20%" => ".20", "30%" => ".30", "40%" => ".40", "50%" => ".50", 
                    "60%" => ".60", "70%" => ".70", "80%" => ".80", "90%" => ".90" }


    def calculation_of_total_cost 
        cost + (tip * cost)
    end

end
```

When I try to go to my homepage (it's set to the new page), I get this error:

`ArgumentError in TippiesController#new`

`Unable to infer the name of the monetizable attribute for 'tip'. Expected amount column postfix is '_cents'. Use :as option to explicitly specify the name or change the amount column postfix in the initializer.`

It refers specifically to the `monetize :tip` in the model ...

**Show.html.erb**

```
<br/><br/>
<h1 class="text-center">Your Total Cost</h1>
<br/><br />


<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Cost of Your Meal:
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= humanized_money_with_symbol @tippy.cost) %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Tip You Picked:
        </td>
        <td>
             <%= number_to_percentage(@tippy.tip * 100, format: "%n%", precision: 0) %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            The Total Cost:
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= number_to_currency(@tippy.calculation_of_total_cost) %>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<br /><br />
<h1 class="text-center">Calculate Your Tip!</h1>

<%= render 'form', tippy: @tippy %>
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(tippy, :html => {'class' => "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
  <% if tippy.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(tippy.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this tippy from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% tippy.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>


  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= f.label :cost_of_your_meal, class: "control-label" %>
    <%= f.text_field :cost, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= f.label :pick_your_tip, class: "control-label" %>
    <%= f.select(:tip, Tippy::TIP_CHOICES, class: "form-control")  %>
  </div>


  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

How do I make this work? Please let me know if more information is needed. Thank you

Comment: Use the decimal type (not float) for **all** the currency columns.

Comment: @max, so, rename all the columns to add `_cents` and make it floats?

Comment: money-rails has its own migration methods - [read the docs](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails)

Comment: @max, dude, I did read the docs. I'm still confused. I'm glad you got it. I didn't. Hence why I'm asking. Honestly. If I figured it out, I wouldn't be asking.

Comment: use `t.monetize :tip` and `t.monetize :cost` in the migration instead.

Comment: @max, ok, so leave my original columns alone, run a migration, put `t.monetize :tip` & `t.monetize :cost`, run `rake db:migrate`, and that's it?

Comment: @max, oh, and change `tip` from floats to decimal?

Comment: No just use the utility methods they have provided. Try actually following the instructions...

Comment: The long explanation is that there is two ways to store money - decimal or integers in the lowest denomination. You're using a float column for one that will lead to rounding errors. Using the migration methods provided by the gem will give you the correct names and types.

Comment: @max, by utility methods, you mean this: `add_money :tippies, :cost` when I run the migration?

Comment: @max, oh, didn't realize that using the migration method would give me the correct names and types ...

Comment: @max ... can I ask another question? I did the migration stuff, and montized it in the migration file, and all that stuff ... using their helper method works, so I guess the migration worked .. but I'm confused. I thought one of the benefits of using the money-rails gem was that if someone inputted in the $ sign, it would still work .. and all I get is a 0 ...

Comment: @max, got that part working. have a different issue to sort out now. thank you for your help. truly. even though it felt snarky, and you thought I didn't read the docs ... which I had but still didn't understand ... your comments went a long way clarifying things for me. so .. for that, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I was confused about this too at first.  The gem wants you to use the first column it provides which is the name of the column with `_cents` added to it.  So your model should have this in it

```
monetize :tip_cents
monetize :cost_cents
```

That column, and a column with `_currency` is created by the gem.

Comment: It's particularly confusing because the syntax in the migration helper is e.g. `t.monetize :tip` but in the _model_ it's `monetize :tip_cents`  - it knows the suffix in one place but not the other.

Comment: I totally agree, this really confused me at first